# Script to place files in folder by extracting date from filename

Tags: regex, bash

I know this has been asked many times, i am terrible with bash and i do not understand the regex format for it. Figured i'd ask for help..

I have a security camera which writes files to a folder in this format:

MDalarm_20170320_084514.mkv

so it goes -- MDalarm_yearmonthday_hourminutesecond.mkv

I want to create a cronjob that will run a script to clean this up, by doing the following:

Taking the files and placing them in a folder for year/month/day then renaming the file to the time only ie: 08_26_15.mkv, even 082615.mkv would be fine if too much of a hassle.

So in the example of MDalarm_20170320_084514.mkv

it should produce

/2017/03/20/08_45_14.mkv

or similar.

The files will be placed in the root folder as they come and the script will run once/twice a day on the folder for cleanup.

I'm decent with regex in php/js/etc.. but the bash one i completely do not understand well enough to get this done. I sincerely appreciate the help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to make the desired file name

```
$echo MDalarm_20170320_084514.mkv | sed -E "s/^MDalarm_[[:digit:]]{8}_//"
```

084514.mkv
and this to make the desired folder name

```
$echo MDalarm_20170320_084514.mkv | sed -E "s/^MDalarm_([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})_.*$/\/\1\/\2\/\3/"
```

/2017/03/20
Use them in shell commands to make folder (if needed) and copy/rename/move file.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i ended up with and it works, thank you Yunnosch for the regex.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ `ls | grep -c mkv` == 0 ]]
then
        echo "NO MKV FILES"
else
        for f in *.mkv; do
                name=`echo "$f"| sed -E "s/^MDalarm_[[:digit:]]{8}_([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})(.*)$/\1h-\2m-\3s\4/"`
                dir=`echo "$f" | sed -E "s/^MDalarm_([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})_.*$/\1\/\2\/\3/"`
                mkdir -p "$dir"
                mv "$f" "$name"
                mv "$name" "$dir"
        done
fi
```

Once someone wrote the regex out i figured out the format, different yet similar.